# Automapper: ConstructUsing isn't called

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm actually upgrading from AutoMapper 2.2 to 7.0.1. The most work is already done.

But now I stuck with the following code:

```
public class DataGridDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public List<DataGridFeldDto> Felder { get; set; }
}

public class DataGrid
{
    public struct ThisObject
    {
        public long Id;
        public List<DataGridFeld> Felder;
    }  
}
```

Mapping:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<DataGridDto, DataGrid.ThisObject>();
    cfg.CreateMap<DataGridFeldDto, DataGridFeld>().ConstructUsing(p => new DataGridFeld(p));
}
```

With the old AutoMapper version it was working. But now I get the following error message:

[image]

It wants to call a constructor without arguments. But why is my contructor with one argument not called?

Thx for any help.

Comment: Are you trying to map from `DataGridDto` to `DataGrid` or `DataGrid.ThisObject`.In either case you need to define a mapper from `DataGridDto` to target's `Felder` property

Comment: I just did a quick test with your source code, it maps without error

Comment: I'm mapping to `DataGrid.ThisObject`. Yes, compiling gives me no errors, but when I start the application the error appear. Do you have a syntax for the mapping from `DataGridDto` to target's `Felder` property?

Comment: What i mean is I have successfully mapped using the given source code. Here is screen shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAdU2.png

Comment: And you are reaching the constructor of DataGridFeld (the one with an argument)?

Comment: Anyone an idea, what's different to the older AutoMapper version?

Comment: I strongly believe the problem lies somewhere else as I have been able to compile without any error with the given code.i can not reproduce the problem

Comment: I had a similar class, where it worked. So I found out, that I had a reverse mapping (`cfg.CreateMap<DataGrid, DataGridDto>()`). When I commented it out, it worked. So there was probably  a change from the old AutoMapper version to the new one.

Comment: I am glad that it worked out